# What activation function is used in the nce_loss?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, activation-function

I am stuck with the [nce_loss](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py#L164) activation function in the [word2vec](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) model. I want to figure out what activation function it uses among all these listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/nn#nce_loss):

> These include smooth nonlinearities (sigmoid, tanh, elu, softplus,
> and softsign), continuous but not everywhere differentiable functions
> (relu, relu6, crelu and relu_x), and random regularization (dropout).

I have searched for it in [this function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/131c3a67a7b8d27fd918e0bc5bddb3cb086de57e/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L872) and somewhere else but failed to get any ideas. I suppose it is the relu* series. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those. It uses [CrossEntropy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/131c3a67a7b8d27fd918e0bc5bddb3cb086de57e/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L1117).